# Difference between various forms of declarations in java

Tags: java, variable-declaration

I am a noob in Java and am someone who is learning Java after python. 
Anyways, I am having a hard time figuring this out.
Suppose I have the class

```
class Bicycle{
      ....
 }
```

and

```
 public class Bicycle{
    ....}
```

what is the difference.
And what about

```
  public static class Bicycle{
              // if this can be a valid class def in first place
   }
```

and then, after this.. lets talk about variables.

```
    class Bicycle{
     int Gear or public int Gear // whats the difference
    }
```

When to use which one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These keywords (or lack of them) are known as access modifiers - in short they control the accessibility of classes or members.

Classes have the following modifiers:

- `public` - accessible anywhere
- (no modifier) - only accessible in same package

Class members have more possibilities:

- `public` - accessible anywhere
- `protected` - only accessible in same package *or* in an extending class
- (no modifier) - only accessible in same package
- `private` - only accessible in same class file<sup>*</sup>

<sup>*Note that [nested classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) can access their outer class's `private` members and vice-versa.</sup>

More information on access modifiers can be found [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) Also see [this helpful article](http://javapapers.com/core-java/access-modifiers-in-java-explain/#&slider1=1) for the basics.

---

**Edit:** I missed your middle example, with `public static class Bicycle` - the `static` here must mean that `Bicycle` is a nested class. See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) (which I had already linked in my subscript) for an explanation of nested classes, which break down into static classes and non-static, aka inner, classes.

Answer (score 3):

Modifiers are Java keywords that provide information to compiler about the nature of the code, data and classes. It is categorized into two types.

1. Access modifiers: public, protected, private.
2. Non-access modifiers (final, Abstract, Synchronized, Native,
   stricfp).

If you don't specify any access modifier before class, it will takes it as a "default" access specifier.

```
public class A     : //access specification would be public. This class can be access any where.

class A            : //access specification would be default. This class can be used only in the same package. So, default is called as package level specification
```

we cannot declare a class as static

```
public static class A{
}
```

But we can declare inner classes as static

```
public class A
{    
     static class B{

     }    
}
```

To get more clarity refer to Access Modifier in java from "SCJP" by kathy sierra